# IE 11 is styling some visited hyperlinks properly but not others on the same page

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hyperlink, cache-control, visited

Please note, I am aware that my question is similar to others that have been posted.  However, none of the others appear to have addressed the EXACT issue I seem to be having nor have they been able to provide viable solutions or decent explanations as to why this is occurring.

### Problem

I am having an issue where some visited hyperlinks in IE 11 honor my `:visited` CSS rules while others do not.  These links are all together on the same page.

The hyperlinks that are honoring CSS `:visited` are to external websites and the ones that don't are those that point back to pages within my application but ONLY in IE and ONLY when they point to my app running in IIS 8.5.  In all other instances (e.g. when I'm working locally and the links point to `localhost` i.e. my app running locally in Visual Studio 2017's default built-in web server) there are no issues, even IE behaves properly.

Again, this **only** has been observed in IE 11 and it **only** affects hyperlinks to pages served by our web server running IIS 8.5.  It's like IE has difficulty admitting these pages are in its browsing history (which they are, I checked).

### Hypothesis

Something is telling me that it has to do with how different web servers serve up content, especially HTTP response headers (see 4th paragraph under Conclusion).

### My App

The following is extracted from my application.  These hyperlinks need to display in red if they have been visited.  (And for the most part they do except as noted above.)

ASP.NET

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="resultsGridView" CssClass="results-grid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField 
            HeaderText="Item #"
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/ItemDetails.aspx?id={0}"
            DataNavigateUrlFields="ItemId" 
            DataTextField="ItemId" 
            ItemStyle-CssClass="item-number">
        </asp:HyperLinkField>
        <asp:BoundField>...</asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
    <AlternatingRowStyle>...</AlternatingRowStyle>
</asp:GridView>
```

CSS

```
.results-grid .item-number {
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.results-grid .item-number a:visited {
    color: red;
}
```

I went one step further and added a test page to my site with hard-coded links.  Three links go to external websites and the other two links are hard-coded versions of the IIS-served links from the grid view (above).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            a:visited {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools Home</a><br/>
        <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/">W3Schools HTML Tutorial</a><br/>
        <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/">W3Schools CSS Tutorial</a><br/>
        <a href="https://example.com/ItemDetails.aspx?id=201725">201725</a><br/>
        <a href="https://example.com/ItemDetails.aspx?id=201774">201774</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

After clicking on each link the W3 Schools links appeared in red (as expected) but my application links did not (only in IE 11)!

(A coworker viewed my test page in Edge and none of the links remained red, but let's not go there right now.)

### Conclusion

I cannot determine what is blocking IE from honoring `:visited` for some links and not others on the same page.

It's not whether the link reference is `https`, in my test page they are all `https`.

It also does not depend on whether the visited pages appear in my history, all 5 links' URLs appear in my history.

It's not whether the pages are being cached by the browser.  Although here's something interesting.  IIS appends `Cache-Control: private` to every HTTP response which I find weird but it is not supposed to affect local browser caching.  It is only supposed to prevent caching at the proxy / intermediate server level.  Even so that does not help explain this odd behavior (does it?).

Again, `:visited` is honored 100% in all other browsers.  It is honored 100% in IE for external sites and links that point locally (running in Visual Studio).  It only trips up in IE on links pointing to the app running in IIS.

Can anyone help explain this phenomenon and / or help me resolve it, please!?

Comment: This is hard to test without a working example. Can you post the output html with the links?

Comment: I'm afraid it wouldn't work.  I suppose I should have specified the site in question is an intranet site so you would not be able to properly test it.  Today I tested links to a couple of public facing sites of ours hoping they would behave similarly but alas they worked just fine.  :( Otherwise I would have obliged your request and supplied you that test.

Comment: And can you post just the `html` fragment with the links?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much an answer as it is an acknowledgement of what I can only describe as a bug in IE and I plan to report this information to Microsoft.

Thanks @meucas for taking time to try to understand this problem.  Sadly, I could not supply you with a valid test case due to the affected links point to an intranet site that only I can browse.

Anyway, here's what I discovered.  It is, in fact, possible for IE 11 to honor `:visited` on all of my hyperlinks, including those in question.  It all has to do with how they are launched.  Let me explain.

I devised another test in which I placed the links inside of an `iframe` and removed the `target` attribute.  It was then and only then when clicking the links (which opened inside the frame, naturally) and subsequently refreshing the page that the links finally appeared in the desired color!

Again, this hack was not necessary for any other browser or links to any external sites.  But it was the ONLY way I could get local links to my IIS 8.5 hosted intranet site to color correctly when visited in IE.

What does this mean for me?  Well, I will not be implementing frames in my app.  So my intranet users are going to be advised to use Chrome.

Peace to you all!